# Call Backbone route on initial page load using Laravel

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Backbone and Laravel so this may be a simple question, but I need my Backbone router to match a URL on initial page load, e.g. localhost/search/query and I'd  ideally like to do this without frag identifiers (or # hashtags or whatever). This is giving me two problems:

1. When I use `Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })` I get a 404 error from Laravel. Is there a way to define a default (index) route for all URLs in Laravel so I won't have to list every possible URL combination I may use?
2. When I don't use `pushState: true` my Backbone router works fine but only if I don't navigate directly to the URL. For example, if I first go to localhost, then localhost/#search/example it works but if I go directly to localhost/#search/example the search route isn't triggered. I think this may be because I only start Backbone.history on document ready but I'm not sure how else to do this. Anyway, here's some code:

   ```
   //app.js
       window.App = {
   Models: {},
   Collections: {},
   Views: {},
   Router: {}
   };

   window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);


   // router.js
   App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
       '': 'index',
       'search/:query': 'search'
   },
   index: function() {
       console.log('the index page');
   },
   search: function(query) {
       console.log('the search page: ' + query);
       vent.trigger('router:search', query);
   }
   });


   // setup.js
   (function() {

       App.cats = new App.Cats();

       App.appView = new App.AppView();

       App.router = new App.Router;

       Backbone.history.start({
       pushState: true
       });

   })();
   ```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default route with "*actions":

http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

```
   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "*actions": "defaultRoute" // matches http://example.com/#anything-here
        }
    });
```

You could also define your starting root:

```
 Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"})
```

And you have to redirect your requests to your index.php
http://www.elcoderino.com/laravel-redirect-redirects-url-to-index-php/

Create .htaccess file in your public directory and add this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```